# JavaScript window.location function not working in localhost folder

Tags: javascript, html, file

In htdocs directory of xampp i have created a list directory and place a simple index.html file in it.

The file contain

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
  <script>
        function Redirect() {
        alert("file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/");
           window.location="file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/";
        }
  </script>
</head>
    <body onload="Redirect();">
   </body>
</html>
```

When i navigate to localhost/list/ it is showing a blank page, and when i have open it directly with any browser it's working fine.

Is there any restriction with this url "file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/".

I want to see File Structure with file:// url.

Comment: What do you see in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<script>
        function Redirect() {
        alert("../xampp/htdocs/");
           window.location="../xampp/htdocs/";
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already in the `xampp` subdir, use a relative URL:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
  <script>
        function Redirect() {
        alert("./htdocs/");
           window.location="./htdocs/";
        }
  </script>
</head>
    <body onload="Redirect();">
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to achieve this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
        function Redirect() {
           alert("htdocs directory here");
           window.location="http://localhost/";
        }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="Redirect();">
   </body>
</html>
```

as htdocs will internally call localhost